# TypeScript applying aspects to classes

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any way to hook into the declaration process of classes in TypeScript?

e.g. consider the following class

```
class Foo extends Bar
{
      constructor() { super(); }
}
```

I currently apply aspects to this type by calling my weaver manually like so:

```
weaver.applyAspects(Foo);
```

Meaning that I modify the behavior of some of the methods on the class.
I would rather see that this happens automagically just by inheriting in the above case the "Bar" super class.

Doing some funky stuff in the constructor seems wrong since that would apply to every new instance, not just the prototype itself.

I guess I could overwrite the __extends function (which is used in the generated javascript output) , but that seems a bit funky too.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use AOP in TypeScript, you can use an existing AOP framework by supplying a definition for it. Here is a full example using jQuery.aop.

Using AOP in this manner won't affect any of your existing definitions as the AOP code is invisible on the code you are cross-cutting.

*aop.d.ts*

```
declare class Advice {
    unweave(): void;
}

declare interface PointCut {
    target: Object;
    method: string;
}

declare class Aop {
    before: (pointCut: PointCut, advice: Function) => Advice[];
    after: (pointCut: PointCut, advice: Function) => Advice[];
    afterThrow: (pointCut: PointCut, advice: Function) => Advice[];
    afterFinally: (pointCut: PointCut, advice: Function) => Advice[];
    around: (pointCut: PointCut, advice: Function) => Advice[];
    introduction: (pointCut: PointCut, advice: Function) => Advice[];
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    aop: Aop;
}
```

*app.ts*

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="aop.d.ts" />

class ExampleClass {
    exampleMethod() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
}

jQuery.aop.before(
    { target: ExampleClass, method: 'exampleMethod' },
    function () { alert('Before exampleMethod'); }
);

jQuery.aop.after(
    { target: ExampleClass, method: 'exampleMethod' },
    function () { alert('After exampleMethod'); }
);

var example = new ExampleClass();
example.exampleMethod();
```

Example source: [AOP with TypeScript](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201211/Blog/AOP-With-TypeScript/).

**Update**

To add the same concerns to a class and all compatible classes, you can't re-use the base class points. This is because the wrapper is the original base-class function wrapped in the points, which will be the wrong implementation for the class that extends the base class.

The only time this would be valid is if your function only called `super()` in which case it would work anyway.

Here is how I would add the same concerns to many classes - the AopHelper would only need to exist once in your program:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="aop.d.ts" />

class ExampleClass {
    exampleMethod() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
}

class SecondClass extends ExampleClass {
    exampleMethod() {
        alert('World');
    }
}

class AopHelper {
    static weave(targets: Object[], method: string, point: Function, advice: Function) {
        for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            point({ target: targets[i], method: method }, advice );
        }
    }
}

var classes: any[] = [ExampleClass, SecondClass];

AopHelper.weave(classes, 'exampleMethod', jQuery.aop.before, () => { alert('Before exampleMethod'); });
AopHelper.weave(classes, 'exampleMethod', jQuery.aop.after, () => { alert('After exampleMethod'); });

var example = new SecondClass();
example.exampleMethod();
```

Comment: Ah - is your question really about how to get classes that extend `ExampleClass` to exhibit the same aspects that were bound to `ExampleClass`?

Comment: yes, exactly, w/o applying them per object instance through constructor hacks.

Comment: Okay, I thought so - check the bit marked "Update" on my answer. You can't really re-use those on the base class, as they will contain a wrapped version of the base class function.

Comment: Ok, but I still have to explicitly call the weaver myself and feed it the subclass?

Comment: Yes - because it will actually generate a different wrapper than it will for the base class.

Comment: Damn @Sohnee, how are you so on-point with Typescript already! I'm blown away haha

Comment: anyone knows where jquery.aop is now maintained if at alle?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/agentframework/agentframework

Here is another AOP for TypeScript utilize the latest decorator feature.

You can add your own interceptor by using decorator

Let's say the following is the behavior you want

```
class Directory {
    public getRoot(): string {
        try {
            return this._root.path;
        }
        catch(err) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do like below in AgentFramework

```
@agent('DirAgent')
class Directory {
     @failure(null)
     public getRoot(): string {
         return this._root.path;
     }
}
```

@failure(null) is a out-of-box attribute which will return the giving value `null` when method throw an error. you also can change to @failure(''), @failure(0), @failure(false) to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a successful implementation of AOP techniques in typescript I'd recommend to use [kaop-ts](https://github.com/k1r0s/kaop-ts/)

Check also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407298/how-to-implement-aop-in-angular-2)

```
class Component extends SomeOtherComponent {
  ...
  @beforeMethod(YourHttpService.getCached, '/url/to/html')
  @beforeMethod(YourHtmlParser.template)
  invalidate (parsedHtml?: any) {
    this.element.append(parsedHtml)
  }
}
...
componentInstance.invalidate()
// explanation below
```