# how to implement aop in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, aop

I am new in Angular 2 but I have good experience in Angular 1.x.

I am getting error:
Cannot find module 'aspect.js/dist/lib/aspect'

Below are my code:

logging.aspect.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {beforeMethod, Metadata} from 'aspect.js/dist/lib/aspect';
@Injectable()
export class LogAspect {

  @beforeMethod({
    classNamePattern: /(Matter|Customer)Service/,
    methodNamePattern: /^(get)/
  })
  invokeBeforeMethod(meta: Metadata) {
    console.log(`Inside of the logger.
      Called ${meta.className}.${meta.method.name}
      with args: ${meta.method.args.join(', ')}.`
    );
  }
}
```

aspect defines an advice which is applied to all method calls starting with get within classes containing the regex-pattern (Matter|Customer)Service in their name. The Metadata available to the advice may contain the actual method- and class names along with the method-call parameters

invoice.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Wove} from 'aspect.js/dist/lib/aspect';
import {Matter} from './Matter.model';
@Injectable()
@Wove()
export class MatterService{
  private url: string;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.url = '/data/matters/data.json';
  }
  get(): Observable<Matter[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(
        (response) => <Matter[]>response.json()
      );
  }
}
```

And please suggest any other way to implement AOP in angular2

Comment: Are you using Angular 2's new AOT compiler? AOT breaks third party decorators, which I think they are trying to resolve. When running under JIT, my custom decorators work perfectly. I realize decorators and AOP are orthogonal, but since you are using decorator syntax, just know it doesn't play well with AOT as AOT erases decorators in a process called lowering where they are transformed into static metadata (this may have been partially resolved). (welcome to AOT: TypeScript with erased decorators and trying-to-be-reified-and-failing-hard-because-the-idea-is-sutpid-in-JavaScript "types")

Comment: Probably you can open an issue on https://github.com/mgechev/aspect.js. Minko Gechev is very involved in Angular as well

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [kaop-ts](https://github.com/k1r0s/kaop-ts)? I find it more intuitive and it is working for me on a company project

```
// LogAspect.ts    
export class LogAspect {
  static log(meta) {
    console.log('Called: ', meta.target)
    console.log('Args: ', meta.args)
  }
}

// YourService.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { beforeMethod } from 'kaop-ts'
import { LogAspect } from './LogAspect'

@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  @beforeMethod(LogAspect.log) 
  get() {
    // ....
  }
}
```